# Why is my NextJS app with Next Intl redirecting to localhost when deployed?

Tags: reactjs, web, next-intl

I am using Next Intl for localization on my app (Next 14.0.4, app router). Next Intl requires the use of a middleware such as this one:

```
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';

export default createMiddleware({
    // A list of all locales that are supported
    locales,
    localePrefix,

    // Used when no locale matches
    defaultLocale: 'es',
});

export const config = {
    // Match only internationalized pathnames
    matcher: ['/', '/(es|gl)/:path*', '/((?!_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)'
    ]
};
```

The app is fully working locally, but once it has been deployed the initial redirect to myapp.com/es instead goes to localhost:8080/es (the port where the NextJS server is deployed).

Is there any workaround for this? I followed both documentation and example code, but the redirect is not working well.

Thank you in advance.

I copied the example line by line, but the app does not work once deployed.

Comment: `next-intl` is not the reason for that issue. Do you use next-auth? Can you provide a repo that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide a repo. Next-auth is not being used. No login is involved in the application, entering the url directly shows the required information when deploying a different branch with no middleware involved.

I believe it has to do with the middleware trying to redirect to localhost (server) instead of the desired domain.